# How to get Trust Sign certificate in VSTO using VS 2013?

Tags: c#, vsto

I have created a Add-In for Ms Word. It is working fine if I publish it and install .vsto file in my system.

But if I use in other it throws error. I think I missed any steps for sign in.

I have followed these steps:

```
1- Go to Project Propertiy -> Signin Tab
2- Checked "Sign the ClickOnce manifest"
3- Create Test Certificate and provide password.
4- Checked the "Sign the assembly"
5- Choose a strong name key file: "myproject_temporarykey.pfx"
```

Then I have publish the project.

Can anybody please suggest what step(s) I am missing here?

Comment: You can't distribute using a test certificate. It needs to be a code-signing certificate from a recognized Certificate Authority.

Comment: @CindyMeister Can you please suggest me link which describe steps or guidance to achieve such certificate with detailed steps?

Comment: No, unfortunately I can't. Nor is such a discussion within this site's guidelines. A Google search should turn up all kinds of information, though.